# PHP specify order in a loop and group html output by that

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array of objects which i would like to output in 3 group by a specified order.
Right now my output groups the data after every 3 element but sadly thats good anymore.
So now I need to group it in this order:

1 group: 1, 4, 7, 10, ... and so on

2 group: 2, 5, 8, 11, ... and so on

3 group: 3, 6, 9, 12, ... and so on

but I couldn't figure out how.

Until now I did it like this:

```
<?php
$group=3;
$count = (count($this->data));
$i=0;
foreach($this->data as $key => &$result){
  $row = ( ((int)$key) % (int)$group)+1;
  if($row==1){
    echo '<div class="row">';
  }
  echo '<div class="item-'.($i+1).'">';
  /*echoing a lots of stuf*/
  echo '</div>';
  $i++;
  if($row == $group || $i == $count){
    echo '<hr />';
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
?>
```

but as I wrote before this is not good anymore

if my question isn't clear than here is my desired html output:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-4"></div>
  <div class="item-7"></div>
  <div class="item-10"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item-2"></div>
  <div class="item-5"></div>
  <div class="item-8"></div>
  <div class="item-11"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item-3"></div>
  <div class="item-6"></div>
  <div class="item-9"></div>
  <div class="item-12"></div>
</div>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I really know what you want, you can do it like this:

```
$group = 3;

$length = count( $this->data );
$matrix = array();
for ( $i = 0, $row_n = 0; $i < $length; ++$i, $row_n++ ) {
    // Reset row.
    if ( $row_n === $group ) {
        $row_n = 0;
    }

    // Set cell.
    $row =& $matrix[$row_n];
    $row[] = 0;

    // Find column nr.
    end( $row );
    $cell_n = key( $row );

    // Update with correct key nr.
    $key = $row_n + $cell_n * $group;
    $row[$cell_n] = $key;
}

/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $matrix );
echo "</pre>";
*/

foreach ( $matrix as $row_n => $row ) {
    echo "\n<div class='row'>";

    foreach ( $row as $cell_n => $key ) {
        echo "\n\t<div class='item-". ($key + 1) ."'>";

        echo $this->data[$key];

        echo "\n\t</div>";
    }

    echo "\n</div>";
}
```

Comment: You are my saviour! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18);

$groups = 3;
$items_per_group = count($data) / $groups;
$i     = 0;
$item  = 0;
$row   = 0;
$open = false;

foreach ( $data as $key => &$result ) {
    if ( $i % $items_per_group === 0 ) {
        $row++;
        $item = 0;

        if ( $open ) {
            echo "\n</div>";
        }

        echo "\n<div class=\"row\">";
        $open = true;
    }

    $nr = $row + $item * $groups;
    echo "\n\t<div class=\"item-$nr\">";
    // echoing a lots of stuf
    echo "\n\t</div>";

    $item++;
    $i++;
}

if ( $open ) {
    echo "\n</div>";
}
```

Might be some error in there, but I hope you get the gist ;)

Comment: hm this outputs like this for me `<div class="row"><div class="row"><div class="row"></div></div></div>`

Comment: That shouldn't be possible... at least it should print out some <div class="item-... s

Comment: oh it prints out <div class="item"> I just shortend the code because i didn't wanted to put long code into the comment section, but basicly it puts the next row inside the previous row

Comment: Can you print out an exact pastebin or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62020/discussion-between-centril-and-laci-k).

Comment: Yes it works now, but can I output the actual data in the same order as the class numbers? Because if you print it out now than lets say the class="item-10" will have the third key in the array

Comment: No, that is intentionally not possible with what I did... then you have to pre-order them... I will add another answer that does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it straight forward, just split origin array into how many groups you want, and then use the new, re-sorted array to printing out HTML.

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

$array = array();
$group = 3; // <--- how many groups you want

$pointer = 0; //init pointer to first group
foreach($a as $value) {
    if($pointer == $group) $pointer = 0; // reset pointer
    $array[$pointer][] = $value; // two detention array have groups -> items
    $pointer++;
}

//use new sorted array print HTMl
foreach($array as $classRow) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    foreach($classRow as $item) {
        echo "<div class='item-".$item."'></div>";  
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb but I don't see how it solves the ordering. As I see whit this methode I would output the groups in same order as they are in the $a array so I would end up whit this: `group1: 1,2,3,4 group2: 5,6,7,8 group3: 9,10,11,12`

Comment: By using the logic: $row_n + $item_n * $group, same as I did in the code I provided. @VVLeon:s method is cleaner than mine - but is a more obvious mechanism ;)